# Acyclic Visitor pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

Here is my attempt at implementing the Acyclic visitor pattern from [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf) in C++11.

The aim is to obtain an implementation which is easy to use and avoids all the boilerplate as much as possible. I would also like to keep the use of macros to a minimum, to keep the code readable.

To use it, one makes the visitable base class (say `N`) inheriting from the class `AbstractVisitable`, which defines the pure virtual method `void accept(Visitor<>&) = 0` (and its *const* counterpart: `void accept(Visitor<>&) const = 0`).

The actual visitable classes `A1, ..., An` (which are subclasses of `N`), need to use the macro `CONCRETE_VISITABLE` which implements the `accept` method.
Finally, an actual visitor is implemented by deriving from `Visitor<A1, ..., An>`, and implementing the method `void visit(Ai&) override {...}` for each class `A1, ..., An`.

There is also the `VisitorFunction` class, which is used to simplify the common tasks of passing a parameter to the visitor and getting a result from its application.

**Visitor.h**

```
#ifndef VISITOR_H_
#define VISITOR_H_

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>


template<typename... Ts>
struct Visitor {
    virtual ~Visitor() = default;
};

template<typename T>
struct Visitor<T>: public virtual Visitor<> {
    virtual void visit(T&) = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... Us>
struct Visitor<T, Us...>: public Visitor<T>, public Visitor<Us>... { };

template<typename... Ts>
using ConstVisitor = Visitor<const Ts...>;


struct AbstractVisitable {
    virtual ~AbstractVisitable() = default;
    virtual void accept(Visitor<>&) = 0;
    virtual void accept(Visitor<>&) const = 0;

protected:
    template<typename T>
    static inline void acceptImpl(Visitor<>& v, T& p) {
        if (auto* av = dynamic_cast<Visitor<T>*>(&v))
            av->visit(p);
        else if (auto* av = dynamic_cast<Visitor<const T>*>(&v))
            av->visit(p);
        else
            throw std::domain_error(std::string() + typeid(v).name() +
                    " does not implement Visitor< " +
                    typeid(T).name() + " >");
    }
};


#define CONCRETE_VISITABLE \
    void accept(Visitor<>& v) override { \
        using TypeOfThis = std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type; \
        AbstractVisitable::acceptImpl<TypeOfThis>(v, *this); } \
    \
    void accept(Visitor<>& v) const override { \
        using TypeOfThis = std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type; \
        AbstractVisitable::acceptImpl<TypeOfThis>(v, *this); }



template<typename Ret, typename... Ts>
struct VisitorFunction;

template<typename Ret, typename Arg, typename... VisitableTypes>
struct VisitorFunction<Ret(Arg), VisitableTypes...>:
        Visitor<VisitableTypes...> {
    VisitorFunction(Arg parameter, Ret initialResult = Ret()):
        parameter(parameter), result(initialResult) {}
    Arg parameter;
    Ret result;

    template<typename T>
    Ret accept(T& v) {
        v.accept(*this);
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename Arg, typename... VisitableTypes>
struct VisitorFunction<void(Arg), VisitableTypes...>:
        Visitor<VisitableTypes...> {
    VisitorFunction(Arg parameter): parameter(parameter) {}
    Arg parameter;

    template<typename T>
    void accept(T& v) {
        v.accept(*this);
    }
};

template<typename Ret, typename... VisitableTypes>
struct VisitorFunction<Ret(), VisitableTypes...>:
        Visitor<VisitableTypes...> {
    VisitorFunction(Ret initialResult = Ret()):
        result(initialResult) {}
    Ret result;

    template<typename T>
    Ret accept(T& v) {
        v.accept(*this);
        return result;
    }
};


#endif /* VISITOR_H_ */
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "Visitor.h"

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


struct Node: public AbstractVisitable { };

struct A: public Node {
    CONCRETE_VISITABLE
};

struct B: public Node {
    CONCRETE_VISITABLE
};

struct C: public Node {
    CONCRETE_VISITABLE
};

struct ZC: public C {
    CONCRETE_VISITABLE
};


struct BasicVisitor: Visitor<A, B, C, ZC> {
    void visit(A&) override {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(B&) override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(C&) override {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(ZC&) override {
        std::cout << "ZC" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct BasicConstVisitor: ConstVisitor<A, B> {
    void visit(const A&) override {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(const B&) override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct FuncVisitor: VisitorFunction<int(std::string), A, B, C> {
    using VisitorFunction::VisitorFunction;

    void visit(A&) override {
        std::cout << "A " << parameter << std::endl;
        result += 1;
    }
    void visit(B&) override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
        result += 10;
    }
    void visit(C&) override {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
        result += 100;
    }
};


struct VoidFuncVisitor: VisitorFunction<void(std::string), A, B, C> {
    using VisitorFunction::VisitorFunction;

    void visit(A&) override {
        std::cout << "A" << parameter << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(B&) override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
    void visit(C&) override {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a; Node& n1 = a;
    B b; Node& n2 = b;
    C c; Node& n3 = c;

    BasicVisitor basic;
    Visitor<>& vis1 = basic;
    n1.accept(vis1);
    n2.accept(vis1);
    n3.accept(vis1);

    BasicConstVisitor basicConst;
    Visitor<>& visConst1 = basicConst;
    n1.accept(visConst1);
    n2.accept(visConst1);

    ZC zc;
    zc.accept(vis1);

    int result = FuncVisitor("PARAM", 50000).accept(n1);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can simplify your `Visitor`-template:

   ```
   template<class... T>
   struct Visitor : Visitor<T>... {
       virtual ~Visitor() = default;
   };

   template<class T>
   struct Visitor<T> : virtual Visitor<> {
       virtual void visit(T&) = 0;
   };
   ```

   It's a shame C++ doesn't have real mixin's, or we would mark `Visitor` with at least two template-arguments as a pure compile-time fiction.
2. You are adding expensive logic to accept a `Visitor<const T>` wherever you accept a `Visitor<T>`. Making all `Visitor<const T>` derive from the corresponding `Visitor<T>` is far cheaper. Just add a specialization:

   ```
   template <class T>
   struct Visitor<const T> : Visitor<T> {
       void visit(T& t) override { visit((const T&)t); }
       virtual void visit(const T&) = 0;
   };
   ```

   Unfortunately, adding explicit specializations allowing a `Visitor<Base>` to visit a `Derived`, where both kinds of visitors might exist, would contravene the pattern's aims. *There* extra-logic is needed despite the runtime-cost.
3. Visitable bases should have something more in common than that they are visitable, which sharply diminishes the usefulness of a baseclass of all visitable types (meaning it should be a mixin for performance, if we had such).
   And a mixin instead of templates or macros for adding the implementations for the `accept`-functions would also be nice.
   Well, let's do the best we can with what we have, the CRTP, to at least diminish the need for even more multiple inheritance:

   ```
   namespace detail {
       struct dummy {};
       template <class T>
       inline void accept(Visitor<>& v, T&) {
           throw std::domain_error(std::string(typeid(v).name()) +
               " does not implement any visitor for " + typeid(T).name());
       }
       template <class T, class X, class... Z>
       inline void accept(Visitor<>& v, T& p) {
           if(auto* av = dynamic_cast<Visitor<X>*>(&v))
               av->visit(dynamic_cast<X&>(p));
           else
               accept<T, Z...>(v, p);
       }
   }

   template <class B = void, class... T>
   struct Visitable : std::conditional<std::is_class<B>::value, B, Visitable<>>::type {
       virtual ~Visitable() = default;
       virtual void accept(Visitor<>& v) { detail::accept<Visitable, T...>(v, *this); };
       virtual void accept(Visitor<>& v) const {
           detail::accept<const Visitable, const T...>(v, *this); };
   };

   template <class B>
   struct Visitable<B> : std::conditional<std::is_class<B>::value, B, detail::dummy>::type {
       virtual ~Visitable() = default;
       virtual void accept(Visitor<>&) = 0;
       virtual void accept(Visitor<>&) const = 0;
   };
   ```
4. A visitor visits, it doesn't accept. If you want to ask a visitor to visit somewhere, a good name is tryVisit.

See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/603efde5268ff999 for the fully-modified version.

Comment: Thanks. Some doubts.
(1) The class hierarchy is changed, since `A,B,C,ZC` do not directly derive from `Node` anymore. The derivation from `Node` is hidden in the definition of `Visitable`. What if the derivation from `Node` is declared `virtual`?
(2) The base class Node, and the subclasses `A,B,C,ZC`, all derive from `Visitable<...>`. According to the Visitor pattern, they are conceptually different, since Node defines the pure virtual method `visit(...)`, which is implemented by the visitable subclasses. I think leaving `Node` implementing a different class `AbstractVisitable` is better.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't see the use of `Visitor<2+ types>` as anything but an implementation-detaill which should be ignored. Dito for any of the `Visitable<T,...>`, where `T` *already* has the two virtual member-functions (Or it's just used for implementing the *real* root-class). So yes, there are new classes in the inheritance-hierarchy, but those should be ignored.